# Effects of cutting carbon nanotube buckypaper

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science

Carbon nanotube buckypaper is a film/paper made from a mesh of carbon nanotube fibers, where each fiber is a bundle of a couple hundred nanotubes. This paper is flexible and tough like normal paper, i.e. you can fold origami with it. It can also be sliced using a regular pair of scissors.

Now I've looked up quite a few papers and manufacturers' websites, but generally the most that people do is confirm that the buckypaper can indeed be cut. What I want to know is **what happens to the carbon nanotubes at the newly created edge of the buckypaper**. Most buckypapers have "clean" edges since they are originally made by drying a solution containing nanotubes, so (I imagine) the nanotubes at the edge aren't crushed, cut off, etc. Would cutting the buckypaper do these things to the individual nanotubes, or to the bundles?

Thank you in advance.